# Logging errors to two appenders

Tags: java, grails, groovy, logback, logback-groovy

I'm trying to configure Logback (in Grails using Groovy configuration) so that:

- any errors (from anywhere) are logged to a rolling file and send an email
- all debug output from my classes is sent to the rolling file

This is what I have so far:

```
appender("ROLLING", RollingFileAppender) { ... }
appender("EMAIL", SMTPAppender) { ... }

logger("my.package", DEBUG, ["ROLLING"], false)
root(ERROR, ["ROLLING", "EMAIL"])
```

It seems that the rolling file gets what I expect (debug from my package at least) but the `EMAIL` appender gets nothing.

How can I send the errors to the `EMAIL` appender?

Comment: I suspect it's a problem with your email appender setup.

Comment: @tim_yates I have replaced the `EMAIL` appender with another `RollingFileAppender` and that files doesn't get anything either. Adding `EMAIL` to `logger("my.package", DEBUG, ["ROLLING", "EMAIL"], false)` works, but only for errors in `my.package` (so I only get emails for errors in my code as opposed to any error anywhere).